# Remove outliers and calculate average

Tags: outliers, mean

I am trying to understand (by reverse engineer) the method a program is using to calculate an average value over a population. The program displays a (very very large) image consisting of tiles. Each tile has some overlap with it's neighbors, expressed in pixels.

In total there are 8625 tiles, hence 8625 overlap values (considering the x-axis overlap only). The program calculates a value that looks like an average of all the overlap values, but in some cases it is not equal to the simple average.

Here are some examples:

If all the tiles have a x-overlap of **50 pixels**, the average is of course **50** and the program also reports **50** as the average value.

If **4312** tiles have an overlap of **1 pixel** and the rest **4313** have an overlap of **100**, the average is **50.50573913**, but the program says **50.511583**.

If **4312** tiles have an overlap of **10** pixels and the rest **4313** have an overlap of **100**, the average is **55.005217391**, but the program says **55.01053**.

If **4312** tiles have an overlap of **50** pixels and the rest **4313** have an overlap of **100**, the average is **75.00289855**, but the program says **75.00585**.

If **4312** tiles have an overlap of **99 pixels** and the rest **4313** have an overlap of **100**, the average is **99,500058** and the **program agrees** (it also reports 99.500058 as the average).

The program outputs a summary file which states the following:

**outlier limit='4'**

I don't know what that number means or what units it is expressed in though. Assuming that the difference in this results is not due to rounding errors (I am pretty sure it is not), what approach could I follow in order to understand it's logic of removing outliers, or make them weigh less somehow in the calculation of the average?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the code so that we could see how the calculations are done. Also, the fact that we don't understand how the program gets the "outlier limit" value is a huge problem. To remove outliers from the calculation, you have to understand what the program considers outliers.

Comment: I don't have the code. As I said, I am trying to reverse engineer this. I can only feed the program with any values I want and check the result.

Comment: If you feed it a lot of values--especially with more extreme splits than 4312/4313--then statistical modeling can be used to identify the formula the program might be using.  Your four cases are not enough, because (at a guess) the program is removing an unknown number of "outliers"--perhaps up to 4--with each calculation.  That gives 25 possibilities, so at a minimum we would want to see 25+2 = 27 results (that show discrepancies) and preferably several times that many results.

Comment: I don't think there is an accurate way to reverse engineer this numerically. You have to work with trial and error and getting to the discipline-specific thing the program is trying to calculate. If it's an image, the values are probably the RGB values of the color of that particular tile. I'm not sure what you mean by overlap: if it's the same vector of RGB values or whether the RGB values aren't different enough to be detected by the human eye.

Comment: @rocinante Because the image is very large, it is split in tiles (smaller rectangular parts of the image). Each tile has some common pixels with it's neighbor tile on the right; the overlap. This is the result of an image stitching process. The program I am trying to reverse engineer, is a viewer for this type of images, which places the tiles correctly next to each other so that the overlap is not evident.

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't answer the question of what aim of the program really is, and what you're supposed to interpret the average as. It seems that the larger the overlap the larger the average. So what? Is this supposed to measure how similar or different the image is?

Comment: The program is a viewer, it just displays the image. If you try to write your own program that simply puts each tile next to the other, there is major overlap that makes the image appear broken. I want to write an algorithm that also stitches the tiles correctly. Thus by inspecting what the original viewer is doing, I discovered that initially it calculates an average overlap for all the tiles, regardless of their individual overlap with their neighbor and afterwards it makes small adjustments for each tile. All this is done by taking into account each tile's overlap value stored in the image.

Comment: An outlier limit of 4 could mean any value at least 4 times the standard deviation from the mean is removed. The question is what values/ mean/sd...

Comment: @MichaelMayer In the examples above, considering values that are within average +/- stdev * 4, would simply include everything, so the average shouldn't be different than the simple average.

Comment: Yes, If the values to be removed are the number of overlapping pixels. Maybe it's something else?

Comment: I cannot tell for sure. For all I know, this value might mean nothing at all.